# Split a giant kml file

Tags: kml

I have a giant kml file with the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <Style id="transBluePoly">
      <LineStyle>
        <width>1.5</width>
      </LineStyle>
      <PolyStyle>
        <color>30ffa911</color>
      </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="labelStyle">
       <IconStyle>
          <color>ffffa911</color>
          <scale>0.35</scale>
       </IconStyle>
       <LabelStyle>
         <color>ffffffff</color>
         <scale>0.35</scale>
      </LabelStyle>
    </Style>
    <Placemark>
      <name>9840229084|2013-03-06 13:41:34.0|rent|0.0|2|0|0|1|T|5990F529FB98F28A1F17D182152201A4|0|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|F|F|0|NO_POSTCODE</name>
      <styleUrl>#transBluePoly</styleUrl>
      <Polygon>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>
            -1.5191200,53.4086600
            -1.5214300,53.4011900
            -1.5303600,53.4028800
            -1.5435800,53.4033900
            -1.5404900,53.4083600
            -1.5191200,53.4086600
            </coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>9840031669|2013-03-06 13:14:22.0|rent|0.0|0|0|0|1|F|E5BAC836984F53F91D7F60F247920F0C|0|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|F|F|3641161|DE4 3JT</name>
      <styleUrl>#transBluePoly</styleUrl>
      <Polygon>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>
            -1.2370933,53.1227587
            -1.2304837,53.1690463
            -1.1783129,53.2226956
            -1.2016444,53.2833233
            -1.3213687,53.3248921
            -1.4809916,53.3039582
            -1.6167192,53.2438689
            -1.5593782,53.1336370
            -1.4296123,53.0962399
            -1.3205129,53.1024090
            -1.2370933,53.1227587
            </coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
```

I need to extract 1 million polygons from this to make it manageable (know geo DB is ultimate solution - looking for a quick fix).

Loading it into a lightweight text editor and just deleting some lines would be my first port of call, but suspect this will take forever and a day (it's 10 Gb, I've got 16 Gb RAM). Just wondering if there is a more intelligent solution from the a linux terminal that avoids having to read it all into RAM. I've seen perl and bash commands for doing this but can't see how they would work for taking a random (or first million) sample: http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/159470-filter-kml-file-xml-remove-unwanted-entries.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a KML parsing library and few lines of code to parse out what you need in a large KML or KMZ file.

**Java**

The [GIScore Java library](https://github.com/OpenSextant/giscore), for example, uses STaX to parse the KML source file one feature at a time so it does not need to load the entire file into memory. The library works very fast so a 10GB won't take very long.

Here's a simple Java program that extracts points from polygons inside a KML file, which doesn't matter how large the KML file nor if the Placemark is deeply nested within folders.

```
import org.opensextant.geodesy.Geodetic2DPoint;
import org.opensextant.giscore.events.*;
import org.opensextant.giscore.geometry.*;
import org.opensextant.giscore.input.kml.KmlInputStream;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    KmlInputStream kis = new KmlInputStream(new FileInputStream("test.kml"));
    IGISObject obj;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.0#####");
    while((obj = kis.read()) != null) {
      if (obj instanceof Feature) {
        Feature f = (Feature)obj;
        Geometry g = f.getGeometry();
        if (g instanceof Polygon) {
          System.out.println("Points");
          for(Point p : ((Polygon)g).getOuterRing().getPoints()) {
            // do something with the points (e.g. insert in database, etc.)
            Geodetic2DPoint pt = p.asGeodetic2DPoint();
            System.out.printf("%s,%s%n",
                    df.format(pt.getLatitudeAsDegrees()),
                    df.format(pt.getLongitudeAsDegrees()));
          }
        }
      }
    }
    kis.close();
  }
}
```

To run, create source file Test.java in the directory src/main/java and copy the code above in the file.

If the Geometry is a [MultiGeometry](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#multigeometry) then you'd need to add a check for that and iterate over the sub-geometries.

Using Gradle, here's a sample *build.gradle* script to run the above test program using the command: *gradle run*

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task run (dependsOn: 'compileJava', type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'Test'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.opensextant:geodesy:2.0.1'
    compile 'org.opensextant:giscore:2.0.1'
}
```

This does require that you install both [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) and [Java Development Kit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) (JDK).

**Python**

Alternatively, you can parse KML using Python with [pykml](https://pythonhosted.org/pykml/) library. Can create multiple smaller KML files with some logic to split the polygons or insert the polygon geometry features into a PostgreSQL database, etc. There is support for pykml in stackoverflow using the [pykml](/questions/tagged/pykml) tag.

```py
from pykml import parser
import re

with open('data.kml', 'r') as fp:
  doc = parser.parse(fp)

for pm in doc.getroot().Document.Placemark:
  print(pm.name)
  # Get the coordinates from either polygon or polygon inside multigeometry
  if hasattr(pm, 'MultiGeometry'):
    pm = pm.MultiGeometry
  if hasattr(pm, 'Polygon'):
    pcoords = pm.Polygon.outerBoundaryIs.LinearRing.coordinates.text
    # extract coords into a list of lon,lat coord pairs
    coords = re.split(r'\s+', pcoords.strip())
    for coord in coords:
        lonlat = coord.split(',')
        if len(lonlat) > 1:
            print(lonlat[0], lonlat[1])
            # add logic here - insert points into DB, etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be too late but some thoughts for you.

I have traditionally modified such code blocks in Microsoft Word using Wild card searches.
While your file may be too large for Word the concepts will work with other similar tools.

I took one block of your file and performed three search and replaces (1) to get the name out and insert it into " marks, (2) to remove the intermediate block of characters and replace them with an = char and (3) to delete the final code block.

It worked like this:

(I actually did some tidy up to remove spaces first - these are probably an artefact of this website rather than the code itself)

```
Replace  [<]Placemark[>][<]name[>](**)[<]/name[>]   by   “\1”

Replace  [<]styleUrl(**)[<]coordinates[>]             by   =

Replace  [<]/coordinates(**)[<]Placemark[>]         by   nothing
```

The square brackets are needed to stop word using some chars as escapes (I may have used them too often?)

The (**) sequence captures everything between those groups and gives them the label \1 which is used in the replace field.

In theory you should be able to do this in one hit using all the three together but this gives a too complex form error for Word until you get right back to basics and cut down the code. So:

```
Replace [<]Place**name[>](**)[<]/name**nates[>](**)[<]/coord**mark[>] by "\1"=\3
```

Will actually work.

Of course you can then easily change the format of your results to what you want (ie not using " or = in the output), and using further search and replaces you can manipulate the output ready for whatever package you want it for.

Wildcard search and replaces are fun!

Bob J.

PS I have written a compiler in Word vba using this concept to take a series of text strings from Excel which hold the essential mapping data and converting them into fully operational kml files. The current input file is >200k chars over 2500 lines and produces a 700k kml file spread over nearly 19,000 lines. It takes about 30 seconds to 'compile'. This is the reverse of your situation.

Answer (score -2):

I am a little bit late, but that answer might help someone. You can split the kml file perfectly using FME DESKTOP, that giant software! using the ModuloCount transformer. check that [Split kml file ModuloCount](https://knowledge.safe.com/questions/32257/split-single-kml-into-multiple-kml-files-with-equa.html)